# call an Oracle function that do an insert/update from PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

we have a function if we call it by using SELECT we get the error code ORA-14551 "Cannot preform a DML operation inside a query"

```
select pkg_tools.replace_site(1121,3343) from dual;
```

how to run this function and get the results

when we run it in SQL developer in this way:

```
declare
v_return VRACHAR2(200);
begin
v_return := pkg_tools.replace_site(1121,3343);
end;
```

works with no errors

**and we need this function to be called inside PHP**

**note:** I can not paste this function here, because it's to long, but it does allot of operations including insert and update!

Comment: How are you connecting to Oracle from PHP? (oci8?).  Just refer to those docs on calling a stored procedure in Oracle.  Quick Googling gave me: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html

Comment: yes we have it, and it works with simple queries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function that does DML cannot be called in a `SELECT` statement regardless of the calling language.

If you want to do DML and return a value, it would make much more sense to create a stored procedure with an `OUT` parameter rather than using a function.  So it would make much more sense to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_name_return( p_1    IN NUMBER,
                                              p_2    IN NUMBER,
                                              p_ret OUT VARCHAR2 )
AS
BEGIN
  p_ret := pkg_tools.replace.site( p_1, p_2 );
END;
```

and then [call that stored procedure from PHP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html)

```
$sql = 'BEGIN proc_name_return( :p_1, :p_2, :p_ret ); END;';
```

If you don't want to do that, my guess is that you could do something like this as well (adapted from one of the scripts on page 164 of the [Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/026973.pdf))

```
<?php
$c = oci_connect('hr', 'hrpwd', 'localhost/XE');
$s = oci_parse($c, "begin :ret :=pkg_tools.replace_site(1121,3343); end;");
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':ret', $r, 200);
oci_execute($s);
echo "Result is: ".$r;
?>
```