# Oracle/Doctrine get result from function where are inserts

Tags: php, sql, oracle, symfony, doctrine

I need to use Oracle function by DBAL Doctrine 2.
The problem is that in this function are insert into commands.
By this I can't use select, not working also call.

I can run it by

```
<?php
$sql = "
    declare
    res number := 0;
    begin 
    res := namespace.functionName(params);
    commit;
    end;";
    $stmt->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Problem is that I can't display in doctrine res value. I can't get this function result.
I know that there should be stored procedure with output param, but isn't. It's not mydb I can't change it and admin doesn't want to change it.

Any idea how I can run such function and get result in DBAL Doctrine?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: In general functions that perform DML are bad practice and not recommended for this very reason. It's somewhat sneaky and can break SQL consistency. I understand you cannot change it, but could you perhaps create a wrapper procedure that calls the function?

Comment: @jaroApp - Have you seen the PHP code at the bottom of this page? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9785340/11611377